# Broadcasting multiplication of two pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix-multiplication, broadcasting

I have two DataFrames, for example:

```
df1 = pn.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2), columns=['A1', 'B1'])
df2 = pn.DataFrame(np.arange(1,7).reshape(3, 2), columns=['A2', 'B2'])

  A1 B1
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5

  A2 B2
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
```

I need multiply df1 and df2 by columns to get a DataFrame with following result:

```
  A1*A2  A1*B2  B1*A2  B1*B2
0     0      0      1      2
1     6      8      9     12
2    20     24     25     30
```

Sizes of df1 and df2 in real task are (1000 columns x 90 000 rows).

I don't want to use double "for" cycle across columns of these DataFrames.

Is there a built-in function or some easy way to calculate it?

Comment: It looks like a polynomial with columns of different dataframes, but not with columns of single dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use <kbd>[`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)</kbd> for efficient performance gain:

```
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame((df1.values[..., None] * df2.values[:, None]).reshape(df1.shape[0],-1))
df.columns = ["*".join(i) for i in itertools.product(*[df1.columns, df2.columns])]
```

[image]

---

The purpose of incorporating `df1.values[..., None]` is to create an extra dimension to the right having shape `(3, 2, 1)` from earlier `(3, 2)` shape of `df1.values`.

Furthermore, `df2.values[:, None]` adds an extra dimension towards the center axis so that it's shape becomes `(3, 1, 2)` from initial `(3,2)` to aid in the multiplication process.

Finally, `reshape` them to take on the same number of rows as that of the original `df1` (or) `df2` 
 (*since both share the same shape in the question mentioned*).

Comment: Excellent! I really like it ))
I need some time to change the conception of work with data in python, because Python is a new programming language for me. Thanks!!!

Comment: If the use of broadcasting seems overwhelming at this stage, I'd recommmend [this post](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc) a good read to grasp those concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use df.multiply() to multiply df with a series and then concat the resulting dataframes like this:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1[["A1", "B1"]].multiply(df2["A2"], axis="index"),
df1[["A1", "B1"]].multiply(df2["B2"], axis="index")], axis = 1)

df3.columns = ['A1*A2', "B1*A2", "A1*B2", "B1*B2"]
```

You get:

```
     A1*A2  B1*A2   A1*B2   B1*B2
0     0      1      0       2
1     6      9      8       12
2     20     25     24      30
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
 
Your solution works and more clear to me as a Java Developer